# Ruby / Rails metaprogramming: generating helper methods on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, metaprogramming, dynamically-generated

I am trying to generate some count methods dynamically for a given array of model names that I can then use in a view/helper:

```
  # create dynamic count methods for each model we want                   
  ['model', 'other_model', 'next_model'].each do |name|
     class_eval{
       "def total_#{name.underscore}s_count
          total_#{name.underscore}s_count ||= #{name.camelcase}.all.count
        end"
      }
  end
```

However, I have a few questions:

1. Where should this code go if I want to be able to call these methods in a view?
2. What class would these methods be added to?  For instance, how would I go about calling them since I'm not sure if they belong to the User, etc. class since they are for a bunch of models.
3. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: What is the advantage of total_model_count over Model.count?

Comment: Keeping direct model calls out of my views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're trying to solve (keeping your views from hitting model methods) isn't solved by delegating the same logic to a view helper. You should be doing this in your controllers if you want to stick to the MVC convention of keeping your views from triggering SQL queries.

```
def index
  models = Foo, Bar, Bat
  @counts = models.inject({}) do |result, model|
    result[model.name.downcase.to_sym] = model.count
    result
  end
end
```

You then have a nice hash of the counts of each of the models passed:

```
@counts #=> { :foo => 3, :bar => 59, :bat => 42 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use a mixin and include it in the relevant model classes. http://juixe.com/techknow/index.php/2006/06/15/mixins-in-ruby/

The methods will be available on the model instances in your views.